# "Out of Memory" Exception when Decrypting an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, out-of-memory

I'm using the System.Security.Cryptography library to encrypt and decrypt xml files. Recently though I've been getting OOM (Out of Memory) exceptions while trying to decrypt a 75MB file. Here's the code I'm using:

```
    using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
    ...
    public static XmlDocument DecryptIntoXmlDoc(string filename)
    {
        //Decrypt the XML
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml(xmldoc);
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider ekey = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

        ekey.Key = encoding.GetBytes(GetMasterKey());
        exml.AddKeyNameMapping("ekey", ekey);
        xmldoc.Load(filename);

        // -- THROWS THE OOM ERROR --
        exml.DecryptDocument();

        //Clear exml
        exml = null;

        return xmldoc;
    }
```

As soon as .DecryptDocument() is called I get the following error:

```
 Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

I haven't been able to find anyone else having this problem, but I have read that if the xml tags aren't properly named/nested, the file can be very large when loaded into memory. 
Would renaming my XML tags to shorter names reduce the size? Is there a way to nest xml tags to reduce the file size?

Is there anything else I could do?

Answer (score 0):

- Run your program under the debugger
- When the OOM exception is thrown, pause and examine the object graph rooted at `exml`. What's actually occupying most of the memory?

Immutable strings are probably the killer here, since some xml parsers can wind up holding your entire doc in memory multiple times.

Comment: I'm new to examining memory problems in .NET, where is the 'object graph'?

Comment: @Nefariousity, it's the tree of objects referenced by a given object. In the VS debugger, you should add `exml` to the watch list, then recursively expand all of its members for a few levels to get an idea of what sort of data it's holding onto.

Comment: Ooooh. I gotcha. Well, it looks like the xmldocument is throwing an OOM message before the exml is. Do you think renaming/restructuring the XML would reduce the file size? Could compression help?

Comment: Compression *might* help. `XmlDocument` takes up a lot of memory because every single node in the DOM has to be copied multiple times, which you can reduced by using a less heavily-nested XML structure. The deeper the level of embedding in the XML document, the more memory it consumes.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that the level of embedding is that significant after all, since experimentation proved me wrong. Anyway.